# Using structured references with Excel tables

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

I hope the title of my problem is correct.
I'll try to give an example.
Lets say I have 2 tables ("table1", "table2"), they are Identical in structure (lets say 3 columns "FirstName", "LastName", "Age").

If I want to get to data in a specific table (age of a person in table1), I know I can do something like vlookup or index(match()).
but, and now I get to the tricky part, I want table name to be refrenced in a cell, that when I drag the formula the table name will change:

```
Age LastName    FirstName
18  Lname1      Fname1
18  Lname2      Fname2
20  Lname3      Fname3


Age LastName    FirstName
22  Lname4       Fname1
22  Lname5      Fname2
21  Lname6      Fname3

so, if I want to get the age of Fname2 from Table1 I would do something like this:
```

=INDEX(Table1[Age],MATCH("Fname2",Table1[FirstName],0))

BUT,
I want the table name to be in another cell so I will be able to drag the formula. put, the table name in cell C3 for example, and do something like:

=INDEX(C3[Age],MATCH("Fname2",C3[FirstName],0))

This obviously doesn't work but is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Nimi

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to reproduce a formula that is referring to `Table1` (such as `=INDEX(Table1[Age],MATCH("Fname2",Table1[FirstName],0))` ) so that the reproduced version is referring to a different table such as `Table2`? And, are you wanting to specify that the name of the other table has been entered as bit of text into cell `C3`?

Comment: yes, in my example c3 has the text "table1", and c4 will be "table2".

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there are several tables with identical structure and you want a general purpose formula which will work on whichever table is specified by name in cell `C3`.

1. `C3[Age]` is meaningless. You want to concatenate the contents of `C3` with the text string `"[AGE]"` - that gives you a meaningful text string to work with.
2. Next, find out about the `INDIRECT` function. This allows you to specify a bit of worksheet such as a cell, range, etc as a text string but treats it as being the cell, range, etc itself
3. Next, find about array formulae. This is because, if you have successfully navigated steps 1. and 2. above, you'll find that INDIRECT doesn't work when its argument (the thing in brackets) is trying to deliver a range of cells (rather than just a single cell). In this case it needs to be specified as an array formula instead of just being a simple formula (which is the default for Excel formulae)

   4. Once you have done all this, you will have the tools to know what you should be using instead of `C3[Age]` and `C3[FirstName]` in the formula you stated in your question.

You can find out about all the terms and functions above easily enough from Excel's help facility and/or online searching. I could, of course, have simply given you an appropriate formula but then what would you have learnt? No pain, no gain.